# Pass the signature of the user (Full Name and an image) from Power Apps to Word document using Power Automate and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, powerapp, word

I have a Power Apps where the user can upload his/her signature image >> then i am calling a Power Automate flow which will populate a word document with the Full name of the user and the signature image.

Currently i am having troubles to understand how i can pass the image the user will upload inside power app to the word document .

Currently i have the following settings:-

1. Inside SharePoint >> I added a document library >> and i added 3 custom columns (FullName, Sig1 + Sig2) >> so i am trying to either store the full image inside an image field (Sig1) or to store the binary date of the image inside a multiple line of text field (Sig2):-

[image: johnjohn123_0-1686005729811.png]

2. then i have this Power Automate flow >> which will create a new file based on the temp.docx template and populate the word document with the full name:-

[image: johnjohn123_1-1686005855749.png]

[image]

so can anyone advice how i can pass the image (signature) from Power Apps to SharePoint and Power Automate please?

thanks in advance for any help.